# Webstorm helper for requiring module

Tags: webstorm, commonjs

I'm looking for a way to require module easily with Webstorm (shortcut, plugin, intention, ...). Here is my use case :

- Given my cursor located at the end of a unknown variable `myVar` somewhere in my JS file.
- When I press a shortcut, I jump at the top of the file and `var myVar = require('')` is inserted with the cursor inside the empty string.
- Then I type the name of the module and I press enter.
- Then the cursor go back at the end of the variable.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can use **Live Templates** for code snippets: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm (it's a platform-wide feature). As for automating it with jumping up and down ... don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-14430](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14430).
You can try developing a custom intention - code intentions use the regular API for intentions. The intention classes need to implement the IntentionAction interface and to be registered using the  bean in the plugin.xml (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA)
See https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/groovy/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/groovy/intentions/control/SplitIfIntention.java - intention sample for Groovi.

See also http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment, http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5298765.

Live Templates is another option, but it just allows expanding certain abbreviation into a code snippet - no jumping, etc. - snippet will be expanded 'in-place'